# What is the formula for Unarmored Movement's bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, monk, statistics

I'm trying to plug in an equation for a monk's unarmored movement in DiceCloud, so that I don't have to change the bonus value whenever it changes. I had a formula, but lost it. Does anyone know what the formula is?

Comment: A formula for what, exactly?  Unarmored movement bonus as a function of Monk level?

Answer (score 19):

You can obtain the correct Unarmored Movement for levels when the character *has* that feature using `math.floor((MonkLevel+6)/4)*5`. This gives correct unarmored movement for levels 2-20; at level 1 this *would* give 5 ft. of unarmored movement, but monks don't have the feature at level 1, so you're fine =)

If you're dead-set on inputting the formula at creation and never looking back, just go for `if(MonkLevel>1, math.floor((MonkLevel+6)/4)*5, 0)`.

DiceCloud's [helper equations page](https://github.com/ThaumRystra/DiceCloud/wiki/DiceCloud-Helper-Equations#monk) has other examples, but I find their suggested Unarmored Movement formula overly-wrought, being composed of many logical tests rather than utilizing the fact that the movement rate changes every 4th level.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I have been looking all morning, this is very helpful and exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Chibeve glad to hear it! I hope that between this post and the equations-page I linked you're good to go. If not, no worries: you can keep asking, we love lots of good questions. If you have any questions about what I mean in the last paragraph feel free to pop into [chat] and ask away. Welcome to the site =)

Answer (score 9):

This is more of an explanation on how to *find* the formula:

We have here is a set of points where \$x\$ is the level and \$y\$ is the unarmored movement bonus. This gives us the set of points \$S = \{(2,10), \space (6,15), \space (10,20), \space (14, 25), \space (18,30)\}\$.

Fortunately all of these points lie on the line \$y = 1.25x + 7.5\$ which can be rewritten as \$y = \frac{5}{4}(x + 6)\$. Unfortunately just using this equation would get us weird things like having 13.75 bonus movement at level 5 and so we have to remove the parts of the line that are giving us values where we don't want them.

Basically we want to make levels 2-5 identical, levels 6-9 identical, and so forth. These are all intervals of length four so we can use the floor function with division by 4 to get exactly what we need:

\$ y = 5 \times \lfloor {\frac {x+6}{4} } \rfloor \$